# Dual citizenship

Tags: canadian-citizens

Does anyone have situation like me I want to apply for my citizenship in Canada and my husband is also applying for my green card at the same time is it ok to do so?

Comment: It is fine to do this. But on what grounds are you trying to acquire Canadian citizenship? They may have an expectation that you make (or have made) Canada the center of your life. I guess it's more a case of honesty than anything else.

Comment: @ouflak I don't see any such requirement other that the objective physical presence requirement, which concerns the period before acquiring Canadian citizenship, not after.

Comment: There was briefly a requirement for Canadian naturalization that the person intend to reside in Canada that was passed by Bill C-24 in 2014, but was repealed by Bill C-6 in 2017.